# Why is this causing a constant 'true' in this while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, constants

Here is the code;

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Do you need instructions for this game? Y/N.");
    char a = input.next().charAt(0);
    // This while loop always comes out as true.
    while (a != 'y' || a != 'n') {
        System.out.println("Please enter either Y/N. ");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (a == 'y') {
        System.out.println("This game is called heads and tails.");
        System.out.println("You must type h (heads), or t (tails).");
        System.out.println("You will need to keep guessing correctly, each correct guess will increase your score.");
    }
}
}
```

Is there an explanation on why it always comes out as true, and is there an alternative way of doing this? I want to have a validation check, where if the user inputs anything other than y, or n, the program shuts down.

The problem is, when I enter the character, y, or n, it shuts down anyway even though I'm using the != (not equals) operator.

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: Because if a is 'y', it's certainly not 'n', and vice versa.

Comment: You need and && not or ||, `y` is not `n` (and vice versa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition inside `while` in
`while (a != 'y' || a != 'n')`
is always true because

- if `a` is equal to `y`, then `a` is obviously not equal to `n`. So,  result is true.
- And again, if `a` is equal to `n`, then `a` is obviously not equal to `y`. So,  result is true.
- And again, if `a` is not equal to `y` or `n`, then also the result is true.

So, the condition inside the `while` is always true. And for this reason, the execution is entering the `while` loop and after printing your message it is exiting.

So using `AND` instead of `OR` may solve your problem, like

```
while(a != 'y' && a !='n') {
    //your work
}
```

And I think you willing to do this like below,

```
public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Do you need instructions for this game? Y/N: ");
        char a = input.next().charAt(0); 
        while (a != 'y') {
            if(a =='n') {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else{
                 System.out.println("Please enter either Y/N : ");
                 a = input.next().charAt(0);
            }
        }

        if (a == 'y') {
            System.out.println("This game is called heads and tails.");
            System.out.println("You must type h (heads), or t (tails).");
            System.out.println("You will need to keep guessing correctly, each correct guess will increase your score.");
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`(a != 'y' || a != 'n')` at least one of the sub-conditions must be true.

Consider the three possible cases:

```
a is 'y':            false || true  gives true
a is 'n':            true  || false gives true
a is something else: true  || true  gives true
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have `a==y`, then  `a != 'n'` is true and `a != 'y' || a != 'n'` is true.
If you have `a==n`, then  `a != 'y'` is true and `a != 'y' || a != 'n'` is true.
If you have `a == other thing`, `a != 'y' || a != 'n'` is true.

It is everytime true with the OR operation. Need use AND.

Answer (score 3):

The character `a` cannot both be `y` and `n`, so the `while` loop is executed for any input.

Besides, the loop is not looping.

Answer (score 3):

You're checking whether a is not equal to 'y' OR a is not equal to 'n'.
This is always true.

Change it into `while ((a != 'y') && (a != 'n'))`.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic should be "a is not y and a is not n"

`while (a != 'y' && a != 'n')`

Comment: any explanation?

Comment: while code only answers work, please still try to explain why this has to be used an why this answer solves OPs problem